# Custom UIView Implemenation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclass

I have customView called BaseView which has a contentView, In the contentView I am adding all other subviews(UILabel, UIButton, etc) in the override init(frame: CGRect) method.

Now I have 10 subclasses of my BaseView, which also overriding init(frame: CGRect) and calling base class init(frame: CGRect) method.

Here all my subclasses looks similar UI to its BaseView, Now there is one subclass of BaseView doesn't want some of the UI Elements in this base class, but I still need to call superview  init(frame: CGRect). How do I change the code without affecting other classes?

```
Class BaseView: UIView {

let contentView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

       let lbl1 = UILabel()
       contentView.addSubView(lbl1)

       let lbl2 = UILabel()
       contentView.addSubView(lbl2)

       self.addSubView(contentView)

     }

  Class subView1: BaseView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

      // This class will show lbl1, lbl2 and lbl3 in the contentview

       let lbl3 = UILabel()
       contentView.addSubView(lbl3) // this contentview is BaseView's ContentView


     }

   // Similarly I have around 10 Subclasses of BaseView which is adding some UI Element to 
    baseview's contentView

   // Question here is, below I am going to create another subclass of BaseView, But I don't 
    want to show lbl1 and lbl2 which is created in my BaseView's contentview

   Class myView: BaseView {

   // this class should not show the base class uilement lbl1 and lbl2, It should show only 
    lbl4 which is created by this class only

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

       let lbl4 = UILabel()
       contentView.addSubView(lbl4) // this contentview is BaseView's ContentView


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change the code without affecting other classes?

You don't. A different approach is needed. Three options are:

- Don't derive the view in question from `BaseView`, and just reproduce whatever `BaseView` functionality you need.
- Continue to derive from `BaseView`, and hide or remove the elements you don't need after `BaseView`'s initialization method. The success of this plan will depend on how tolerant `BaseView` is when elements it expects are missing.
- Refactor the functionality in `BaseView` into some new class that has the behavior that's common to *all* your views, and have your one outlier view and `BaseView` each descend from that new class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach to implementing the required functionality.

Create a parent class with a content view where you want to show the content.

```
class SuperView: UIView {
let contentView = UIView()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Inherit BaseView class from SuperView class and you can inherit other classes from BaseView class.

```
class BaseView: SuperView {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    contentView.addSubview(UILabel()) // UILabel 1
    contentView.addSubview(UILabel()) // UILabel 2
    self.addSubview(contentView)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Inherit SubView class from SuperView class to add different properties and functions that you want. Here you don't need to inherit from BaseView class.

```
class SubView: SuperView {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    contentView.addSubview(UILabel()) // UILabel 3
    self.addSubview(contentView)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

I hope it will help you to implement the required functionality as you want.